# differentiating between still and yet

Tags: adverbs

***UPDATED***:

Do you still live in the same place or have you moved? (**How could we understand whether the time has elapsed?**)

Are the following correct?

Do you live in the same place yet or have you moved?

Don't you live in the same place yet or have you moved?

Comment: I don't see what's colloquial about the first one ("Do you still live in the same place or have you moved?")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at this [link](http://linguapress.com/grammar/points/still-yet-already.htm) on *yet* vs *still*.

To sum up, *still* is used to imply a continuing action in *affirmative* sentences.
So, basically you'd use still as follows: `"I'm still in the same house."`

If you want to use *still* in a sentence with *not*, it's important to place *still* in the correct position before or after not. To borrow an example from the link:

```
"I do not still have the picture"
```

I don't have the picture anymore, though I had it earlier. Note the *not* is **before** *still*.

```
"I still do not have the picture"
```

I am waiting for the picture to arrive. The *not* is **after** *still*.

For *yet*, it's not usually used in affirmative sentences and is mainly used with actions that aren't yet over or finished. Like -

"I haven't yet finished moving into my new place" - I'm in the process, but it's not done.

It's common to find *yet* with *not*, as shown above (have not).

It's rare to find *yet* in an affirmative sentence. It can be used in questions as follows -

```
"Has he found out about the place yet?"
```

to ask if he has found out about the new house/place in the time that has elapsed. You wouldn't use *still* here.

Think of *still* as inertia of action and *yet* as inertia of inaction.

Comment: hasn't he found the place yet? has he found the place yet? do you feel any difference between these?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. 
I hope you've got your answer.
Just in case, here are my 2 cents:
Hasn't and Has is more an expectation issue.
"Has he found the place yet?" would be more patient, and "Hasn't he" might indicate impatience/surprise. But that also depends on tone, so this is not a complete answer.