# discerning between stiil and yet in sentences

Tags: adverbs

Would you tell me if I am right?

The only difference between the following is the fact that the period of time as to first one is longer than the second one-- emphasis.

"I still do not have the picture"

"I do not have the picture yet"

[enter link description here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41405/differentiating-between-still-and-yet)

Answer (score 1):

Both the adverbs mean the same that when you speak that sentence the *matter* in concern is not done. It is pending, in other words.

But then, there is a *slight* (but indeed interesting) difference! My source for this answer is [British Council's Learn English:](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/just-yet-still-already)

> ‘Yet’ is used to talk about something which is expected to happen. It means ‘at any time up to now’. It is used in questions and negatives.

*yet* usually comes in the end of the sentence.

On the other hand,

> ‘Still’ is used to talk about something that hasn’t finished – **especially when we expected it to finish earlier.**

The example follows:

> You ***promised*** to give me that report yesterday and you ***still*** haven’t finished it.

That said, both actually mean the delay or things that have not happened till now. I don't think there's a 'time constraint' in this **the way** you think.

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, what about the link that I have just provided. One of the dear members has expressed a kind of time constraint.

Comment: *still would go there* - He has *still* not found the place! But then, when both the words mean the same, we have to depend on our own volition and decide which looks *natural!*